# Assigning Value To Select2 V4 From LocaStorage Is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to assign a value to select2 from localStorage but it's not working. However, while assigning the value of localStorage hardcoded it's getting assigned.
Here's what I'm trying:

```
var selectedLangs = localStorage.getItem('agentLangs'); //["4","5"]
    $('.agentLanguages').val(selectedLangs).trigger('change');
```

If I assigned the value directly then it works:

```
$('.agentLanguages').val(["4","5"]).trigger('change');
```

Any Idea what could be the issue?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` returns a string, you probably need to `JSON.parse` it.

Comment: That's perfect; It's working. Thanks for helping